# Solve an equation for a specific unknown?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this equation:

```
((a * (1 - t)^2 + 2 * d * (1 - t) * t + g * t^2) - j)^2+((b * (1 - t)^2 +
  2 * e * (1 - t) * t + h * t^2) - k)^2 +
  ((c * (1 - t)^2 + 2 * f * (1 - t) * t + i * t^2) - l)^2 == r^2
```

Its long and very badly writed but I count on Wolfram to simplify it. But here I have a lot of unknown while in real all variable except $t$ are known, I plan to use it in a video game so even right know I don't know $a$, $b$, $c$, ... These variable will be known at calculation.
So I want to tell Wolfram, only $t$ is unknown and obtain the result $t=a+b^2...$.

Currently I have tried solve [my equation] for $t$ and searched in the equation page but I didn't find my solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is Wolfram Alpha specific rather than about Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do but generates a very large solution:

```
Solve[((a*(1 - t)^2 + 2*d*(1 - t)*t + g*t^2) - 
  j)^2 + ((b*(1 - t)^2 + 2*e*(1 - t)*t + h*t^2) - 
  k)^2 + ((c*(1 - t)^2 + 2*f*(1 - t)*t + i*t^2) - l)^2 == r^2, t]
```

In fact there are four solutions given as a list in the above result. This is to be expected from a fourth-order polynomial equation.

Comment: Thx but it says "Standard computation time exceeded..." will the Browser toolbar use my computer and not be limited or I have to buy pro (or optimise the request but I don't know how to do that, I'm very new with this) ?

Comment: This site is about Mathematica, not about Wolfram Alpha. I assumed you were working with Mathematica, where the above code works.

Comment: Ah ok, (I was thinking Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica to be the samethings)